# How to create lookup field on visualforce for person account using a custom controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, lookup, person-accounts

I Currently have a visualforce page where I want a user to be able to select a existing person account or create a new one.

I am getting the error: Attribute value in apex:inputField must contain only a formula expression that resolves to a single controller variable or method

Visualforce

```
<apex:page controller="TestController">
<apex:inputField  value="TestValue">{!pa.name}</apex:inputField>
</apex:page>
```

Apex

```
public class TestController {
  public Account pa{get;set;}
  public void AdminController() {    
    pa = [select name from Account where isPersonAccount  =true limit 1];  
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is by creating a custom field that has a lookup field to Account with a [lookup filter](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_lookup_filters.htm&type=5) to only show Person Accounts (Use record type to filter or isPersonAccount boolean). You can add this field on any object, I would prefer to add this to a custom object.

Then all you need is bind the field to the `inputField`.

```
public class TestController {
 public CustomObject__c pa{get;set;}
 public TestController() {    
     pa = new CustomObject__c();  
 } 
}
```

_ vf page

```
<apex:page controller="TestController">
  <apex:inputField value="{!pa.Account__c}"></apex:inputField>
</apex:page>
```

Here `Account__c` is a lookup field on the Custom Object to Account with lookup filter to the Person Account.